# Do I need to use the Kinect SDK to develop for Xbox?

Tags: xna, c#, legal, xbox360, kinect

I was wondering if I need to use the Kinect SDK from Microsoft to develop games for the Xbox 360. I know there are other libraries such as OpenNI and OpenGL, but can I develop games using Kinect for those? Also where would I get a License to develop for the 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question explicitly asks how to write Kinect games for the 360. My understanding is that XNA on the 360 doesn't support the Kinect. It seems you can possibly use it on Windows, but as I've never tried I can't confirm (but a quick internet search seems to confirm you can).

Unless you're an authorised 360 developer (think have a publisher that's an approved XBox 360 developer or some sort of track record making games that would help get your foot in the door talking to MS) you're not going to get access to the full blown XDK that allows C++ based development and access to the Kinect device. There are no other alternatives for 360 development.

Answer (score 3):

The Xbox360's primary development tool is C# and Microsoft's XNA framework.

You will need a copy of Visual C# (Express is usable forever once you get a free registration key):

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

And the XNA SDK:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

Here are some good sites to check out to get started:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/

http://www.riemers.net/

You can get the App Hub membership here:

http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/membership

The membership allows you to upload 10 Xbox360 games and test your games on your console, among some other benefits.

Comment: If for whatever reason you don't want to use C#, you could use another .Net language like Visual Basic or Boo.  However, I can't confirm that they work on Xbox.

Comment: The question seems to ask specifically about developing for the Kinect on 360. This isn't possible with XNA and there aren't other options available to non-approved developers.

Comment: @Boreal I live on C# :)